# How to successfully get a dropdown selection to trigger the dispatch of an action in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have started a simple React/Redux system using react-redux, mostly copied from examples. (I want eventually to develop a more complex system that redux will be suitable for.)

I have things called Places, with an identifier placeCode. All the details of each Place are held in a Place database on a server. Generally things seem to work OK (with much help from documentation and blogs). However I cannot find out how to do something that I would have expected were simple.

There is a placeReceived **action** and a fetchPlace routine to do a database lookup on the server to get the Place record

```
function placeReceived(place) {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.PLACE_RECEIVED,
    place,
  };
}

export function fetchPlace(placecode) {
  return dispatch => fetch(`/places/${placecode}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => dispatch(placeReceived(data.data)))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

The relevant portion of the **reducer** is

```
const initialState = {
  place: { placeCode: 'HcN' },
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  const updated = { ...state };

  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.PLACE_RECEIVED:
      updated.place = action.place;
      return updated;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

One component is PlaceDetails, which shows the placeCode and placeName.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class PlaceDetails extends Component {

  render() {
    const place = this.props ? this.props.place : { placeCode: '' };
    const placeName = place.placeCode ? `${place.placeCode} ${place.placeName}` : 'Missing Place';

    return (
      <Fragment>
        {placeName}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  place: state.plac.place,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlaceDetails);
```

If I connect these together by putting

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(fetchPlace('BBR'));
  }
```

into the class PlaceDetails to look up a constant Place then it all works, and the PlaceDetails show BBR and its placeName looked up from the databse.

However what I want to do is select the placeCode **via a dropdown** (actually an Ant Design Cascade) and I assumed I could just call fetchPlace in the `onChange()` of that dropdown. The cascade works fine and it definitely calls fetchPlace with the correct argument, however I see no sign that place is fetched (PlaceDetails stubbornly continues to show its default, and breakpoints have not shown the action being dispatched).

I feel that I am not understanding some basics of React or Redux.

How should I be getting the selection in the dropdown to trigger the fetching of the place, and hence the updating of the PlaceDetails?

*Update*

As requested by streletss I have created a [stripped down sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/92o8yjr4ny) of my client. I am new to all this, so it has taken a while.

I don't see how to put the node.js server into the sandbox, so I presume I need to find a way to mock the fetches. I have looked at sinon-stub-promise and MockServer and they seem complicated. fetch-mock seems simpler but I have not tried it yet. Any advice welcome, else when I have set up the mocks I will update this question again.

Comment: please, recreate your component in https://codesandbox.io/s

Comment: u can use dis url to get places if u need https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all ..
try to replace fetch url to this api inside your sandbox code

Comment: one thing i noticed is for getting data on `componentDidMount` you are doing `dispatch(fetchPlace('BBR'))` but for getting data on drop down selection you are doing `fetchPlace(value[value.length - 1])`. you should do `dispatch(fetchPlace(value[value.length - 1]))`

Answer (score 0):

> I feel that I am not understanding some basics of React or Redux.

How true that was. After several days research and reading, and especially [Valentino's tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-redux-tutorial-beginners/), and refactoring with the container/presentational pattern, I have now got my little system working.

It turns out that what I was following at first had helped me with mapStateToProps, but the importance of mapDispatchToProps had passed me by.

As an aside, CodeSandbox seems very useful.